# edit and update user model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

i have registration and login forms that work well, but I am trying to edit the user profile but i don't seem to make it work, below are my codes, can you please point me the mistake i am making?

/views.py

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=request.user)
        form = UserDetailsUpdate(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('profile')
    form = UserDetailsUpdate(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```

/models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

/forms.py

```
class UserDetailsUpdate(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('image', 'website', 'sex')
```

/template/profile.html

```
{% if form %}
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="container">
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </div>
        </form>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the template where you render your form?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i just did that

Comment: Hello @WillemVanOnsem please have you taken a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at your model, i think you have some few things you missed,

- there is no way to associate the UserProfile model to the onetoone relationship you have with the User model.
- secondly the instance been passed to UserDetailsUpdate form should have reference to the UserProfile model.
- Lastly in order to get the update fields populated with current data use also have to use the answer to my second point.
  below is your solution.

## Create your models here.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.profile.save()
```

the above code will create a corresponding userprofile model anytime a new user is created.

/views.py

```
@login_required()
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # current_user = UserProfile.objects.get(username=request.user)
        form = UserDetailsUpdate(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('profile')
    form = UserDetailsUpdate(instance=request.user.userprofile)
    return render(request, 'profile.html', {'form': form})
```